# why the order of adding a string in variable is swapped

Tags: bash, echo, cat

I try to perform the below string but the output for "${prefix}${R1}" is always _R1_001.fastq.gze Hi1803_1_S96_L002 which should be  "Hi1803_1_S96_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz". No idea why the order is swapped. Thanks

```
for prefix in `cat /binf-isilon/PBgrp/jfb841/RNA-seq_germination/RNA-seq_filename.txt` 

do

raw_data_loc="/binf-isilon/PBgrp/jfb841/RNA-seq_germination" 

R1="_R1_001.fastq.gz"

R2="_R2_001.fastq.gz"

echo "Processing sample ${prefix}" 
salmon quant -i /binf- 
isilon/PBgrp/jfb841/annotations/transcriptome_index --libType A -1 
${raw_data_loc}/"${prefix}${R1}" -2 ${raw_data_loc}/"${prefix}${R2}" --- 
p 48 -o quants/${prefix}"_quant" &

done
```

Comment: where to add indent?

Comment: @BaiBing : Please [format your script properly as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also, I suggest running your script with `set -x`.

Comment: Maybe your txt file from which you read prefix has windows line endings (CRLF = `\r\n`) check the output of `file ....txt` and convert the file using `dos2unix` if needed.

Comment: 'cat /binf-isilon/PBgrp/jfb841/RNA-seq_germination/RNA-seq_filename.txt'

Hi1803_1_S96_L002
Hi1803_10_S105_L002
Hi1803_11_S106_L002
Hi1803_12_S107_L002
Hi1803_13_S108_L002
Hi1803_14_S109_L002
Hi1803_15_S110_L002
Hi1803_2_S97_L002
Hi1803_3_S98_L002
Hi1803_4_S99_L002
Hi1803_5_S100_L002
Hi1803_6_S101_L002
Hi1803_7_S102_L002
Hi1803_8_S103_L002
Hi1803_9_S104_L002

Comment: The RNA-seq_filename.txt is one column with names without space

Comment: Indent the code here already.

Comment: your code works for me